# Changing Text and Photos on existing website

Tags: html

I do not specialize in the coding or html... I was assigned to change text, add content, and change photos on our existing company website. The designer gave me access to the control panel in which I went to as follows:

control panel > file manager pro > public > content > components > home > view > index.html

Where a window popped up and i scrolled down the window to find the text area in which I made changes to the content. I saved it and nothing happened with the website, nothing was changed.  If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it as I am still learning and the designer is not getting back to me.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without knowing the designer's dev environment or the way the site is hosted :/. It's possible that the site is hosted somewhere else, and you have to manually push the new index.html file. It could also be that there's simply a delay for changes to appear on the site.

Comment: The file manager pro, or control panel is through the AT&T website.  http://prntscr.com/fwy9n5   http://prntscr.com/fwya00  I am really at a lost of how to go about it as I have made changes in the html but nothing is changing.